# Getting errors while making backup of whole centos with tar

Tags: linux, centos, tar, logging

I am trying this command

```
tar cvpzf /TEMP_BACKUPS/backup.tgz --exclude=/proc --exclude=/lost+found  --exclude=/tmp --exclude=/TEMP_BACKUPS --exclude=/mnt --exclude=/sys / > /TEMP_BACKUPS/mylog.txt
```

and i am getting this error. I have tried twice

```
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
tar: /dev/log: socket ignored
tar: Removing leading `/' from hard link targets
tar: /selinux/policy: Cannot open: Invalid argument
tar: /var/spool/postfix/public/flush: socket ignored
tar: /var/spool/postfix/public/cleanup: socket ignored
tar: /var/spool/postfix/public/showq: socket ignored
tar: /var/spool/postfix/private/defer: socket ignored
tar: /var/spool/postfix/private/virtual: socket ignored
tar: /var/spool/postfix/private/proxywrite: socket ignored
tar: /var/spool/postfix/private/verify: socket ignored
tar: /var/spool/postfix/private/anvil: socket ignored
tar: /var/spool/postfix/private/lmtp: socket ignored
tar: /var/spool/postfix/private/bounce: socket ignored
tar: /var/spool/postfix/private/relay: socket ignored
tar: /var/spool/postfix/private/scache: socket ignored
tar: /var/spool/postfix/private/retry: socket ignored
tar: /var/spool/postfix/private/error: socket ignored
tar: /var/spool/postfix/private/rewrite: socket ignored
tar: /var/spool/postfix/private/tlsmgr: socket ignored
tar: /var/spool/postfix/private/local: socket ignored
tar: /var/spool/postfix/private/discard: socket ignored
tar: /var/spool/postfix/private/trace: socket ignored
tar: /var/spool/postfix/private/smtp: socket ignored
tar: /var/spool/postfix/private/proxymap: socket ignored
tar: /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock: socket ignored
tar: /var/www/html/run/wsgi.1458.0.1.sock: socket ignored
tar: /var/www/html/run/wsgi.4861.1.1.sock: socket ignored
tar: /var/www/html/run/wsgi.1178.0.1.sock: socket ignored
tar: /var/www/html/run/wsgi.1179.0.1.sock: socket ignored
tar: /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: socket ignored
tar: /var/run/abrt/abrt.socket: socket ignored
tar: /var/run/rpcbind.sock: socket ignored
tar: /var/run/portreserve/socket: socket ignored
tar: /var/run/nscd/socket: socket ignored
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

what do i need to do to make full backup

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Note that your `tar` command is completing successfully; it's just complaining about the socket entries.  Tiffany is suggesting a mechanism for filtering out those particular error messages, although `tar` will still exit with an error code.

You could also feed a list of sockets to `tar`'s `-X` option to have them excluded from the backup, e.g:

```
# find / -type s -print > /tmp/sockets-to-exclude
# tar cvpzf /TEMP_BACKUPS/backup.tgz -X /tmp/sockets-to-exclude \
  --exclude=/proc --exclude=/lost+found  --exclude=/tmp \
  --exclude=/TEMP_BACKUPS --exclude=/mnt --exclude=/sys / > /TEMP_BACKUPS/mylog.txt
```

The advantage to this technique is that it makes `tar`'s exit code more useful (that is, you can use the exit code to decide whether or not the backup completed successfully).

You could also shorten your command line by replacing your other `--exclude` options with a single `-X` (aka `--exclude-from`) and simply listing them in a file.

Comment: should I exclude `/run` as well?

Comment: the standard error of `find / -type s -print > /tmp/sockets-to-exclude` should be redirected somewhere (e.g., `/dev/null`), otherwise find complaints that some files created during the search do not exist.

Answer (score 20):

The fact is tar is successful, but prints out warning that those socket files are ignored

GNU tar actually provides an option to suppress warnings. You could ignore the "socket ignored" errors using the below command which avoids running a find command that could take a long time to complete.

```
tar --warning='no-file-ignored' -cpzf  backup_name.tar.gz  /folder_to_backup
```

[This links has more details](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_section/tar_27.html)

Answer (score 11):

Sockets are zero level files that are used by daemon processes to communicate with each other. They are created and destroyed as necessary when the daemons start and stop. They can safely be ignored.

You can always get rid of them with `tar  <my_options> 2> >(grep -v 'socket ignored' >&2)`

Comment: i didn't understand , do u mean that by ignoring sockets , will my tar run ok without exiting

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. This is more useful than just writing how you can ignore this warnings.